# Translation of "Baller"?

Tags: translation, vocabulary, conversation

Was trying to explain to my one friend what does it means by "**He's a baller**".  The closest I got is "他很酷" but that's just the same meaning as "He's cool".  Is there a more...descriptive translation?

Edit:  Here's an example:   "I hit 4 of a kind twice at the casino tonight, it's baller"

Comment: Have checked [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=baller) but it seems the usage of this word is a little capricious.

Comment: @Stan agree and I would assume it's mostly used in US regions, by non-seniors

Comment: The chief meaning of "he's a baller" on-line is to say someone masters some ball game.  The next biggest is to say he is a partier.  If you don't think either of those is right, then you think most people using the term in English get it wrong.  Maybe so.  But if you want the term used in some specific sense you have in mind, then you can't expect this list to render it in Chinese.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty guess it's actually a term derived from the definition you mentioned.  And yea my friend does get the meaning yet I was wonder if there's a better answer.  Guess it just can't be rendered as

Comment: is there a term for 江湖上成功的人

Comment: Why not use 球者, and people might infer from context that it is an analogy.

Comment: @倪阔乐 just curious if "他很牛" means something similar?

Comment: Can you explain which specific meaning do you have in mind in English?

Comment: @NS.X. think it's goes with something like being awesome and being cool at the same time... but it could be an adjective (I think) as well, something like "I hit 4 of a kind twice at the casino tonight, it's baller"

Comment: @Alex: could you perhaps edit this information into the question? In its current form, it's a bit hard to figure out the exact nuances of "baller" that you want to convey, particularly without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on urban dictionary's definition, a baller is:

> A thug that has "made it" to the big time.

当屌丝逆袭成功之后，他就成就屌丝之王了，又称：“屌王“， ”屌霸“， “逆袭屌”

Comment: That sounds like it, however does 屌 considered swearing / foul language in this content?

Comment: 屌 also refers to male reproductive organ. Although not classy, but definitely not swearing.

Comment: Wait. Thug == 屌丝?

Comment: @Stan I used to think 屌丝 means weak, but seems like it's not?

Comment: @Alex not exactly. 屌丝 is the opposite of 高富帅(tall, rich, handsome), and rich or not is the crucial criterion. This word is often used jokingly.